# Hadoop JobHistoryServer don't save a specific Job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a cluster of PCs with a Hadoop installation. The Service work well, and I executed a lot of jobs without problems. For research purposes, I send the job logs to a JobHistoryServer Service.

For one Job the History Service didn't save the stats. If I execute other Job, with the same configuration, the stats are saved. But I re-run this Job, and the History Server don't save the stats.

The history server log (file mapred-hduser-historyserver-master.log):

```
2017-05-13 11:28:59,634 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2017-05-13 11:31:59,634 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2017-05-13 11:34:59,634 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2017-05-13 11:37:59,634 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2017-05-13 11:40:59,634 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
```

My question is: How can I start to debug what is happening?

More data:

- There aren't problems of Java Heap Space of History Server (I see many of that when I search)
- The workers and master have enough disks space.
- HDFS space it's Ok also.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I found the problem. One of the workers had the date out of update. I set the right date and the History Server persisted the log of the Job correctly.